# ReactJS local server crashes after editing file in Emacs even without saving

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emacs

I'm trying to follow the ReactJS tutorial at https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html. I'm using Emacs to edit *index.js*, and when I edit the file (add a newline, let`s say), even without saving the file, instantly the server crashes and I get this output:

```
/home/myname/Code/project/reactapp/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.
js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/myname/Code/project/r
eactapp/src/.#index.js'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/myname/Code/project/reactapp/src/.#index.js'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myname/.npm/_logs/2020-06-25T03_16_55_466Z-debug.log
```

I've checked for the file .#index.js and it's a hidden file that looks like this

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myname myname   32 Jun 25 13:16  .#index.js -> myname@myname-pc.4444:1593054984
```

When I try to open it it tells me that it's a symbolic link to a file that doesn't exist.

I've tried restarting my machine, creating a new ReactJS project, and I'm really not sure what's going on. I've never used npm/nodejs/reactjs before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Emacs uses lockfiles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LockFiles) to avoid editing collisions. `.#index.js` is a lock file automatically created by Emacs in your case because `index.js` is edited but not yet saved. If it's your local computer, it's unlikely that collision will happen, so it's safe to disable this feature by

```emacs-lisp
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

As [Rorschach mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567370/reactjs-local-server-crashes-after-editing-file-in-emacs-even-without-saving/62571200#comment110662389_62571200) in a comment, if you want to disable lockfiles for this specific project only, the best way is to set it as a [directory variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html):

```emacs-lisp
;; /home/myname/Code/project/reactapp/.dir-locals.el
((nil . ((create-lockfiles . nil))))
```

Comment: I've been adding `((nil . ((create-lockfiles . nil))))` to my .dir-locals.el in node project roots to deal with this for a while.  It would be nice to fix it on the JS side, in the webpack configuration tho

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the emacs lockfile is causing a bug in how watchpack (a part of webpack) uses chokidar (a filesystem monitor).

The [answer from viam0Zah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62571200/73603) with comment from Rorschach are good for stopping emacs from writing the lock file.

Instead, I went looking for why the lockfile is crashing webpack, and found the general area, but couldn't quite understand it.

I did come up with a total hack temporary fix: edit your `node_modules/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js` file. On line 57 change from `followSymlinks: false` to `followSymlinks: true`.

Any edits to `node_modules` like this will, of course, be lost the next time you update versions or otherwise reload your node modules.

I think the actual problem relates to this issue, which I don't have the willpower to wade through right now: https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/130

Answer (score 2):

Comment out line 19 of node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js as a work around until it is fixed.  That's better than disabling lockfiles and possibly losing edits.

Comment: I'm curious, what edits could you lose potentially? What is your scenario? I have lockfiles disabled and I never lost any edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure webpack to ignore certain files.
If you are using create-react-app, the file is located at:
**node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js**

To get webpack to ignore emacs lockfiles and backupfiles, add this ignored statement to watchOptions (should start on line 98).

> ignored: /.#|~$/,